# ngOnInit and Lazy Network Requests

Tags: angular

I have created a custom accordion component in Angular that takes on the following form:

```
<accordion>
    <drawerOne></drawerOne> 
    <drawerTwo></drawerTwo>
    <drawerThree></drawerThree>
    <drawerFour></drawerFour>
</accordion>
```

I'd like to fire off some network requests but only when the views of the drawers are initialized. Because they are all children of the accordion components, their `ngOnInit`'s are all being fired simultaneously.

I was wondering what you all thought might be a good way to achieve something similar to an `ngOnInit` firing once per drawer.

Maybe some sort of function that is fired when the accordion is opened? I also want to do `lazy network requesting` if that's even a thing. If I go to `drawerThree` and then back to `drawerTwo` I want the data from the previous network request to either still be there, or cached, instead of having to make another request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code provided I just explain my solution, hope it works for you

I assume you have two component for accordion and accordionItem and using ng-content

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-item (onInitialized)="dosomethinghere()" (onActivate)="doAnotherthinghereonActivation()">
       <drawerOne></drawerOne> 
    <accordion-item/>
    <accordion-item>
       <drawerTwo></drawerTwo>
    <accordion-item/>
    <accordion-item>
       <drawerThree></drawerThree>
    <accordion-item/>
    <accordion-item>
       <drawerFour></drawerFour>
    <accordion-item/>
</accordion>
```

1. Add an Output event `onInitialized` on accordion-item
2. Fire `onInitialized` when it's needed to be initialized
3. Write some handlers for it and load data
4. In case you want each drawer loads data it self create a reference like `#drawerOne` for it and call a method on that in your handler

By this way also you can do your lazy data loading and caching data

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest one I can think of is this :

1 - create a drawer class

```
export abstract class Drawer {
  public abstract getContent();
}
```

2 - Make your drawers extend it

```
export class DrawerOne extends Drawer implementsOnInit {}
// You'll figure the 3 others ;)
```

3 - Name your components by ViewChilds and trigger a click on them

```
<drawerOne #D1 (click)="D1.getContent()"></drawerOne> 
<drawerTwo #D2 (click)="D2.getContent()"></drawerTwo>
<drawerThree #D3 (click)="D3.getContent()"></drawerThree>
<drawerFour #D4 (click)="D4.getContent()"></drawerFour>
```

**What does this do ?**

This forces you to create a `getContent` method (absrtact = you need to create it in the child classes), and when you click on your drawers, you trigger this method and make the call to your back-end. So basically, your click has two functions : open/close the drawer, and load its data

**TODO**

You will have to make a condition on the click, saying that when you close the drawer, you actually unsubscribe from your data fetching service. I'll let you handle that, but if you need help, just let me know !

Comment: Because you mentioned the keyword `unsubscribe`, I'm assuming that Observables will have to be used somewhere in here